# iOS Enterprise Developer Program - rules

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

The company I work for wants to distribute (in a public link) an app with In-House signature. I'm pretty sure Apple denies this kind of thing, but I didn't find anything about in the official documentation/contract.

Does anybody know how exactly it works or where it is written?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Apple's page is pretty clear on that: "Distribute your proprietary, in-house iOS apps to employees or members of your organization. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime."

Looks like **no** to me!

Or just call Apple. The developer support number is 800 633-2152.

Comment: I've seen it, but I'm still looking for a formal NO!

Comment: Apple's developer support number is: 800 633-2152. I always received a quick response to my questions there.

Answer (score 0):

See the question "[Security of over-the-air distribution of enterprise iPhone apps - OTA iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108123/security-of-over-the-air-distribution-of-enterprise-iphone-apps-ota-ios)" to see limitations of distribution via enterprise (the certificates are the problem).

More info about deployment can be found here:

- http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: Do you know where it is written in the documentation/contract? I really need this in a formal way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is: NO.

You cannot share a link for your app to people outside your organization - that breaches your agreement with Apple. However, I know that some companies do that kind of "beta invitations". Here's my old answer on ["How do we publish our ios application for only our customers via our servers?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496648/how-do-we-publish-our-ios-application-for-only-our-customers-via-our-servers), take a look.

So you think you're stuck with 50 promo codes per version and 100 devices for internal testing? Thankfully, NO! :) [This article](http://sixtostart.com/onetoread/2012/distributing-3000-copies-of-an-ios-game/) will shed some more light on how one company distributed over 3000 copies legally. It's worth a read IMO.

EDIT: if you're looking for a formal NO, search for iOS Developer Enterprise Program, where it's stated explicitly that if you share apps outside your organization you account may be suspended/closed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in Member Center. Selct Your Account Tab and then Legal Agreements in the left pane.